# How to set up fluent API relationship in zero to zero or one to one relationship

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, ef-fluent-api

I am a beginner in ASP.Net MVC and Entity Framework. And I am stuck at setting a type of relationship using Fluent API.

So, I have two Models:

Model A

```
Public Class A
{
    [Key]
    public int AId {get; set;}
    public string AName {get;set;}
}
```

Model B

```
Public Class B
{
   [Key]
   public int BId {get; set;}
   public string BName
}
```

Business Logic:

1. A can exist independently
2. B can also exist independently
3. But during certain scenario for example Let's say when when user enter "2" in textbox in UI. In that scenario, I want A to have BId stored in it.
4. **Once BId started existing in Table A, It cannot exist again in Table A**.

Now the reason I want to set this relationship is when BId is getting stored in A Table, I need to be sure that it is not some random integer. I want the promise that BId getting stored in A table does actually exist in B Table.

My thinking:

I need `Optional Unique Foreign Key Relationship`. But I am not sure how to achieve it in CodeFirst Fluent API Approach

Below is what I have till now.

Model A

```
Public Class A
{
    [Key]
    public int AId {get; set;}
    public string AName {get;set;}
    public int BId {get;set;}
    public virtual B {get;set;}
}
```

**Question 1:** 
How to make sure that when ever I BId in A table, it must be a PK present in B Table
**Question 2:**
 What type of entity relatioship I am dealing with? 1..0 or 1..1 or something else?

**Edit**

I want something like:

```
dBModelBuilder.Entity<A>()
                    .HasOptional(r=> r.B) 
                    ........
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to explicitly configure this. Just make A's FK Property nullable and the conventions will create the mapping you want.  EG:

```
public class A
{
    public int AID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? BID { get; set; }
    public virtual B B { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public int BId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

To do this in the Fluent API would look like:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<A>()
            .HasOptional(a => a.B)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(a => a.BID);
```

Comment: But I want to learn the FLuent API approach. What if I did not follow the Primary Key (EF) convention. then how I would have set up this relationship

Comment: "But I want to learn the FLuent API approach", Then start here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591620(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: Sir, I made an attempt in the edit section. Can you kindly see once. I want something like that

Comment: Note this is B (0..1) to (0..N) A relationship. Or in EF terms, optional one to many.

Comment: @IvanStoev: I forgot to tell one more thing "Once BId started existing in Table A, It cannot exist again in Table A."

Comment: So, once I have put a BId = 4 in table A. And somehow I am putting 4 again in Table A I should get an exception.

Comment: @Unbreakable This is one of the relationships EF6 does not support very well.

Comment: For SQL Server that would require a filtered index.  No way to do that with the fluent API, although you can add one through custom SQL in a migration.  EG `create unique index uk_BID on A(BID) where BID is not null;`

Comment: Hi, it's strange to see that the only way to identify the optional side of a ZERO to ONE FK is by using an empty {WithMany()} statement. As you won't find this example in any of the MSDN doc's and I've searched many SO articles for proper solution. Thanks ! (+1 upvote)